# why the outputs of tcpdump behaves defferent from three times handshake's definition

Tags: linux, macos, tcp, tcpdump

I ran the tcp's connection test on mac os using tcpdump and telnet. Here is my command:

```
telnet localhost 3000
tcpdump -i lo0 port 3000
```

and here is the result:

```
16:44:23.751241 IP6 localhost.59405 > localhost.hbci: Flags [S], seq 396289691, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 896927289 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:44:23.751315 IP6 localhost.hbci > localhost.59405: Flags [S.], seq 588037038, ack 396289692, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 896927289 ecr 896927289,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:44:23.751331 IP6 localhost.59405 > localhost.hbci: Flags [.], ack 1, win 12743, options [nop,nop,TS val 896927289 ecr 896927289], length 0
16:44:23.751345 IP6 localhost.hbci > localhost.59405: Flags [.], ack 1, win 12743, options [nop,nop,TS val 896927289 ecr 896927289], length 0
16:44:53.758011 IP6 localhost.hbci > localhost.59405: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 12743, options [nop,nop,TS val 896957275 ecr 896927289], length 0
16:44:53.758085 IP6 localhost.59405 > localhost.hbci: Flags [.], ack 2, win 12743, options [nop,nop,TS val 896957275 ecr 896957275], length 0
16:44:53.758101 IP6 localhost.hbci > localhost.59405: Flags [.], ack 1, win 12743, options [nop,nop,TS val 896957275 ecr 896957275], length 0
16:44:53.758188 IP6 localhost.59405 > localhost.hbci: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 12743, options [nop,nop,TS val 896957275 ecr 896957275], length 0
16:44:53.758260 IP6 localhost.hbci > localhost.59405: Flags [.], ack 2, win 12743, options [nop,nop,TS val 896957275 ecr 896957275], length 0
```

the third line's ack value is 1 instead of 588037039, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

> http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump
>
> the ack sequence number is a small integer (1). The first time
>   tcpdump sees a tcp 'conversation', it prints the sequence number from
>   the packet. On subsequent packets of the conversation, the difference
>   between the current packet's sequence number and this initial sequence
>   number is printed. This means that sequence numbers after the first
>   can be interpreted as relative byte positions in the conversation's
>   data stream (with the first data byte each direction being '1'). '-S'
>   will override this feature, causing the original sequence numbers to
>   be output.